# use Mage::registry to get the product data

Tags: magento-1.9

> Hi I am using the below method to get the product data as Sku &
>   Category ,I could get all data expect the category name .

```
public function getProductData()
{
    $p = Mage::registry('current_product');

    $data = array();

    $data['content_name']     = $this->escapeSingleQuotes($p->getName());
    $data['content_ids']      = $this->escapeSingleQuotes($p->getSku());
    $data['content_category']     =$this->escapeSingleQuotes($p->getCurrentCategory());
       return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Get all Categories Of a Product Like This :-**

```
$catCollection = $p->getCategoryCollection();
foreach($catCollection as $cat){
  print_r($cat->getData());

}
```